# Wildcard subdomains and friendly URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

This is what I would like to do with htaccess (or whatever you suggest):

I want to allow users to publish pages,photos,videos,... and give them each a subdomain of their choice (ex: `john.mysite.com`).

Here's how a URL can be -really Tumblr like (it would be great if it'd work like Tumblr :)-

```
john.mysite.com/photos
john.mysite.com/photos/album/123456789
john.mysite.com/news/123456789
john.mysite.com/news/category/123456789
```

Using htaccess I can make `whatevertheusernameis.mysite.com` be served by `mysite.com/user.php`
Then in `user.php` I can see who the user is analyzing `HTTP_HOST` (getting 'whatevertheusernameis' and checking my DB) and I can know what to show (photos,videos,news,pages,...) reading `REQUEST_URI`.

I would like certain URL to work as follow:

```
john.mysite.com/ajax/ajax.php    ->    mysite.com/ajax/ajax.php
john.mysite.com/images/img.png   ->    mysite.com/images/img.png
```

but if, for example, I'm in `john.mysite.com/photos/album/123456789/` this will be served as `john.mysite.com/photos/album/123456789/ajax/ajax.php` that, of course, won't work...

Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: A reverse proxy for the "static" pages is a good idea.

Comment: Add a condition to your rewrite rules (using `RewriteCond`) to ignore such requests (do not rewrite them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is add a condition before all your other rewrites:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ...
```

Those directives will tell Apache to always serve actual files (f), directories (d) and symbolic links (l) and use the sub-domain to identify the location of the user data (photos, etc).